# Need to change styling on MUI button based on state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've googled this ad nauseum and haven't found a solution for my particular case. Please bear in mind I'm a total React newb.

I have a MUI button that changes state based on whether or not the user has contributor rights. If not, it disables. The code works, but the disabled state default color doesn't mesh with the theme, and I'd like to be able to change it within this file itself (changing within the theme is not an option right now). I can't find a solution.

Code below. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks for reading!

```
"use client";

import { useContext } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import s from "./HeaderNav.module.scss";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { Add } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { AuthContext } from "@/utils/contexts/AuthContext";

type Route = {
  path: string;
  label: string;
};

export default function HeaderNavigation() {
  const { isContributor } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const buttonBackgroundColor = isContributor ? "#DCB45B" : "#dc071b";
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();
  const { push } = router;
  const handleCreateClick = () => {
    push("/requirements/create");
  };
  let routes: Route[];

  switch (pathname) {
    case "/special-page":
      routes = [
        // ...navigation items specific to '/special-page'
      ];
      break;

    default:
      routes = [
        { path: "/", label: "Home" },
        { path: "/requirements", label: "Requests" },
        // ...default navigation items
      ];
      break;
  }

  return (
    <nav className={s.navigation_header}>
      <Link className={s.logo} href="/">
        <Image src={drmtlogo} alt="Logo" />
      </Link>
      <ul className={s.nav_items}>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <Link href={route.path}>{route.label}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        sx={{
          fontWeight: 600,
          backgroundColor: buttonBackgroundColor,
        }}
        startIcon={<Add />}
        onClick={handleCreateClick}
        disabled={!isContributor}
      >
        Add Request
      </Button>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add conditional styling:

`sx={{color: isContributor ? 'green' : 'red', fontWeight: 600, backgroundColor: buttonBackgroundColor}}`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your sass file you could try adding this:

```
button[disabled='true'] {
  color: // add desired color here
}
```

this will add the style to all disabled buttons in the app. If you want it on a select few buttons, you can add a classname and use the **:disabled** attribute

Answer (score 0):

if here disabled={!isContributor} is receiving a false value maybe it's that why is not working, does it get disabled when isContributor true?

Comment: Please, format your answer's code :)

Comment: @MrFrenzoid bueno perdón